# PRAW mentions not displaying when looping thru them

Tags: python, praw

I am trying to make a bot, that will reply when mentioned with PRAW API.

```
import praw
import time

print("Bot running..")
//login info


def replyFunc():
    print(reddit.inbox.mentions(limit=None))
    for mention in reddit.inbox.mentions(limit=None):
        print(f"{mention.author}\n{mention.body}\n")
        mention.reply("**test**")
        mention.read()

while True:
    replyFunc()
    print("Loop")
    time.sleep(2)
```

No errors printed and nothing is and print(f"{mention.author}\n{mention.body}\n") is not printed

Edit:
when I get all inbox items using reddit.inbox.all(limit=None) code works well, but with it, program will register all messages in inbox not just mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for me, the mentions function isn't working (maybe a PRAW bug) so I made a small workaround.

```
def replyFunc():

for mention in reddit.inbox.unread(limit=None):
        if "mention (u/botname)" in mention.body:
            print(f"{mention.author}\n{mention.body}\n")
            mention.reply("**test2**")
            mention.mark_read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be okay, i think you do not have any mentions to loop through.

Do you get `print('loop')` in `stdout`? If so then the above is the only reason you are not getting the logs.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks! "loop" is displaying even with stdout so no error there. The problem is in getting the mentions, which are not registering

Comment: Please check if you have mentions in the account that you are querying. Also you can try printing out `print(len(reddit.inbox.mentions(limit=None)))` just before the for loop to check the length of the array.

Comment: reddit.inbox.mentions(limit=None) is not treated like a list so len couldn't be used. Also I checked and I have mentions

Comment: What is the type of reddit.inbox.mentions(limit=None)? is it a generator function? If so you can convert to list by `list()` method. Also can you shave the log of `print(reddit.inbox.mentions(limit=None))` if its printed?